# How to iterate over list with tuples and use it as key, value in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am beginner with python, trying to resolve the issue i run into.
I have a list of tuples:

```
print(dic_list)
[('Primary Contact', 'Luk'), ('Phone Number', '111'), ('Email Address', 'luk@sky.com'), ('Alternate Contact', 'Luk2'), ('Phone Number', '333'), ('Email Address', 'Luk2@luk.com'), ('Primary App Contact', 'Bill'), ('Phone App Number', '555'), ('Email App Address', 'bill@luke.com'), ('Alternate App Contact', 'Bill2'), ('Phone App Number', '777'), ('Email App Address', 'Bill2@luke.com'), ('Primary Contact', 'Sky'), ('Phone Number', '222'), ('Email Address', 'sky@sky.com'), ('Alternate Contact', 'Sky2'), ('Phone Number', '444'), ('Email Address', 'Sky2@sky.com'), ('Primary App Contact', 'Way'), ('Phone App Number', '666'), ('Email App Address', 'way@sky.com'), ('Alternate App Contact', 'Way2'), ('Phone App Number', '888'), ('Email App Address', 'Way2@sky.com')]
```

I would like to use those tuples as key:value in another dictionary

```
print(FormDic)
{'Contacts': {'Contacts': {}, 'Contacts1': {}, 'Contacts2': {}, 'Contacts3': {}}}
```

I am almost there but something i am doing wrong, i used following for loop:

```
for dic_key, dic_value in list(dic_list):
    for key in FormDic['Contacts'].keys():
        FormDic['Contacts'][key][dic_key] = dic_value
        

{'Contacts': {'Contacts': {'Primary Contact': 'Sky', 'Phone Number': '444', 'Email Address': 'Sky2@sky.com', 'Alternate Contact': 'Sky2', 'Primary App Contact': 'Way', 'Phone App Number': '888', 'Email App Address': 'Way2@sky.com', 'Alternate App Contact': 'Way2'}, 'Contacts1': {'Primary Contact': 'Sky', 'Phone Number': '444', 'Email Address': 'Sky2@sky.com', 'Alternate Contact': 'Sky2', 'Primary App Contact': 'Way', 'Phone App Number': '888', 'Email App Address': 'Way2@sky.com', 'Alternate App Contact': 'Way2'}, 'Contacts2': {'Primary Contact': 'Sky', 'Phone Number': '444', 'Email Address': 'Sky2@sky.com', 'Alternate Contact': 'Sky2', 'Primary App Contact': 'Way', 'Phone App Number': '888', 'Email App Address': 'Way2@sky.com', 'Alternate App Contact': 'Way2'}, 'Contacts3': {'Primary Contact': 'Sky', 'Phone Number': '444', 'Email Address': 'Sky2@sky.com', 'Alternate Contact': 'Sky2', 'Primary App Contact': 'Way', 'Phone App Number': '888', 'Email App Address': 'Way2@sky.com', 'Alternate App Contact': 'Way2'}}}
```

The final results should be like:

```
Contacts:Contact1: {
Primary Contact: luke, 
Phone number: 111,
email address: luke@sky.com, 
Alternate Contact: luke2, 
phone number: 333, 
email address: luk2@luke.com}, 
Contact2:{
Primary Contact: bill, 
Phone number: 555, 
email address: bill@luke.com, 
Alternate Contact: bill2, 
phone number: 777, 
email address: bill2@luke.com}, 
Contact3:{
Primary Contact: sky, 
Phone number: 222, 
email address: sky@sky.com, 
Alternate Contact: sky2, 
phone number: 444, 
email address: sky2@sky.com}, 
Contact4:{
Primary Contact: way, 
Phone number: 666, 
email address: way@sky.com, 
Alternate Contact: way2, 
phone number: 888, 
email address: way2@sky.com
```

Something is not right with for loop i tried enumarate and with range but can not get values to be added to dictionary as per above.
Any help would be greatly appreciate

Comment: Do you want `dict(dic_list)`?

Comment: You can use ```for dic_key, dic_value in dic_list.items()``` instead of ```for dic_key, dic_value in list(dic_list):```

Comment: Well, i can not use dic_list.items() as this is not the dictionary but list. 
print(type(dic_list))
<class 'list'>

Comment: We prefer text to images and small examples to large. Suppose `dic_list` had, say, 3 items, and you wrote a complete example program that we could run. Then we'd have an easier time testing an answer.

Comment: You say you are doing something wrong... but what? What do you want the output to be and how is this output different? You are adding the same contact info to each contact in `FormDic`. Is that good or bad? "contact1" doesn't seem to have anything to do with the contact info you have. Its perplexing.

Comment: Please show the code instead of pictures, we cannot copy paste it and test it

Comment: I fixed this post by removing images and add them as code. Also i added how results should be, my apology for not being specific.

Answer (score 0):

The flat `dic_list` actually contains 6 infos per contact, all sequential.
The key is to iterate by chunk of 6, gather the infos in one dict, and put it in the result dict.

Here is the code :

```
dic_list = [('Primary Contact', 'Luk'),         ('Phone Number', '111'),     ('Email Address', 'luk@sky.com'),
            ('Alternate Contact', 'Luk2'),      ('Phone Number', '333'),     ('Email Address', 'Luk2@luk.com'),
            ('Primary App Contact', 'Bill'),    ('Phone App Number', '555'), ('Email App Address', 'bill@luke.com'),
            ('Alternate App Contact', 'Bill2'), ('Phone App Number', '777'), ('Email App Address', 'Bill2@luke.com'),
            ('Primary Contact', 'Sky'),         ('Phone Number', '222'),     ('Email Address', 'sky@sky.com'),
            ('Alternate Contact', 'Sky2'),      ('Phone Number', '444'),     ('Email Address', 'Sky2@sky.com'),
            ('Primary App Contact', 'Way'),     ('Phone App Number', '666'), ('Email App Address', 'way@sky.com'),
            ('Alternate App Contact', 'Way2'),  ('Phone App Number', '888'), ('Email App Address', 'Way2@sky.com')]

FormDic = {"Contacts": {}}
assert len(dic_list) % 6 == 0
for i_contact, contact_infos_start_index in enumerate(range(0, len(dic_list), 6)):
    contact_infos = list(list(dic_list[contact_info_index])
                         for contact_info_index in range(contact_infos_start_index, contact_infos_start_index + 6))
    FormDic["Contacts"]["Contacts" + str(i_contact)] = contact_infos

print(FormDic)
```

and the result (edited for formatting) :

```json
{"Contacts": {
    "Contacts0": [
      ["Primary Contact", "Luk"],
      ["Phone Number", "111"],
      ["Email Address", "luk@sky.com"],
      ["Alternate Contact", "Luk2"],
      ["Phone Number", "333"],
      ["Email Address", "Luk2@luk.com"]
    ],
    "Contacts1": [
      ["Primary App Contact", "Bill"],
      ["Phone App Number", "555"],
      ["Email App Address", "bill@luke.com"],
      ["Alternate App Contact", "Bill2"],
      ["Phone App Number", "777"],
      ["Email App Address", "Bill2@luke.com"]
    ],
    "Contacts2": [
      ["Primary Contact", "Sky"],
      ["Phone Number", "222"],
      ["Email Address", "sky@sky.com"],
      ["Alternate Contact", "Sky2"],
      ["Phone Number", "444"],
      ["Email Address", "Sky2@sky.com"]
    ],
    "Contacts3": [
      ["Primary App Contact", "Way"],
      ["Phone App Number", "666"],
      ["Email App Address", "way@sky.com"],
      ["Alternate App Contact", "Way2"],
      ["Phone App Number", "888"],
      ["Email App Address", "Way2@sky.com"]
    ]
  }
}
```